# Remove redundant also calls

Tags: kotlin, sockets, optimization

I'm working with TCP communication and use Ktor library.

I have packets that come, and the first byte is the packet's lengths.

Likewise, I read the packet from what is documented on the protocol API, and sometimes I have to skip the remaining bytes of the packet, so I subtract what I have read to this message length.

At the present time, I call `also { messageLength -= length }` on each reading, but the code is unreadable.

```
@Test
    fun ktorTests() {
        runBlocking {
            val selectorManager = SelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)
            val socket = aSocket(selectorManager).tcp().connect("server.slsknet.org", 2242)

            val openReadChannel = socket.openReadChannel()
            val openWriteChannel = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)

            val login = "Test"
            val pwd = "159753"
            openWriteChannel.write {
                it.put(
                    ByteMessage().writeInt32(1)
                        .writeStr(login)
                        .writeStr(pwd)
                        .writeInt32(160)
                        .writeStr((login + pwd).toMD5())
                        .writeInt32(1)
                        .getBuff()
                )
            }

            while (true) {
                var messageLength = openReadChannel.readIntLittleEndian()
                val code = openReadChannel.readIntLittleEndian()

                println("ServerClient received: Message code:" + code + " Packet Size:" + (messageLength + 4))
                when (code) {
                    1 -> {
                        if (openReadChannel.readBoolean().also { messageLength -= 1 }) {
                            val greetingLength = openReadChannel.readIntLittleEndian().also { messageLength -= 4 }
                            val greeting = ByteArray(greetingLength)
                            openReadChannel.readFully(greeting, 0, greetingLength)
                                .also { messageLength -= greetingLength }
                            val ip = openReadChannel.readIntLittleEndian().also { messageLength -= 4 }
                            println("Logged In.")
                        }
                openReadChannel.discardExact(messageLength.toLong())
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on ho could it be done ?

Comment: One possibility is to read the entire packet into a byte array or byte buffer

Comment: Or just split your code into independent statements ?  Like: `val isOk = channel.readBoolean() ; messageLength -=1 /* new line */ if (isOk) { /* new line */ val greetingLength = openReadChannel.readIntLittleEndian() ; messageLength -= 4 /* new line */ etc. }`

Comment: @amanin I should use this everywhere I read packets, not really like I want the code will become unreadable

The easieast way is maybe to inherit from ByteReadChannel from ktor but even if it is open class, I can't inherit or extends function of that class

Comment: @Sercurio you can use composition over inherithance; With Kotlin `by` operator, you can wrap the original channel with minimal boilerplate.

Comment: @amanin could you provide exemple code with ByteReadChannel for exemple ?